# Hibernate attempting to insert null in foreign key column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sql-server-2008, jpa

I have two classes CaretakerDetails and Devices there is a OneToMany relationship between the two entities but when I am trying to insert the object it is throwing the following exception:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Caretaker_Id', table 'Emomtracking.dbo.Device_Details';

Caretaker Class is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Caretaker_Details", schema = "dbo", catalog = "Emomtracking")
@DynamicUpdate
public class CaretakerDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer caretakerId;
private EmomLookup emomLookup;
private String caretakerName;
private Date createdDate;
private String caretakerNumber;
private List<DeviceDetails> deviceDetailses = new ArrayList<DeviceDetails>();

public CaretakerDetails() {
}

public CaretakerDetails(String caretakerName, Date createdDate, String caretakerNumber) {
    this.caretakerName = caretakerName;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
    this.caretakerNumber = caretakerNumber;
}

public CaretakerDetails(EmomLookup emomLookup, String caretakerName, Date createdDate, String caretakerNumber,
        List<DeviceDetails> deviceDetailses) {
    this.emomLookup = emomLookup;
    this.caretakerName = caretakerName;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
    this.caretakerNumber = caretakerNumber;
    this.deviceDetailses = deviceDetailses;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "Caretaker_Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getCaretakerId() {
    return this.caretakerId;
}

public void setCaretakerId(Integer caretakerId) {
    this.caretakerId = caretakerId;
}

// @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "Pairing_Status")
public EmomLookup getEmomLookup() {
    return this.emomLookup;
}

public void setEmomLookup(EmomLookup emomLookup) {
    this.emomLookup = emomLookup;
}

@Column(name = "Caretaker_Name", nullable = false)
public String getCaretakerName() {
    return this.caretakerName;
}

public void setCaretakerName(String caretakerName) {
    this.caretakerName = caretakerName;
}

@Column(name = "Created_Date", nullable = false)
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return this.createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

@Column(name = "Caretaker_Number", nullable = false)
public String getCaretakerNumber() {
    return this.caretakerNumber;
}

public void setCaretakerNumber(String caretakerNumber) {
    this.caretakerNumber = caretakerNumber;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "caretakerDetails", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
public List<DeviceDetails> getDeviceDetailses() {
    return this.deviceDetailses;
}

public void setDeviceDetailses(List<DeviceDetails> deviceDetailses) {
    this.deviceDetailses = deviceDetailses;
}

}
```

Device entity is as follows:

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "Device_Details", schema = "dbo", catalog = "Emomtracking")


public class DeviceDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer deviceId;
private CaretakerDetails caretakerDetails;
private String deviceNumber;
private Date createdDate;

public DeviceDetails() {
}

public DeviceDetails(CaretakerDetails caretakerDetails, String deviceNumber, Date createdDate) {
    this.caretakerDetails = caretakerDetails;
    this.deviceNumber = deviceNumber;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "Device_Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getDeviceId() {
    return this.deviceId;
}

public void setDeviceId(Integer deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Caretaker_Id", nullable = false)
public CaretakerDetails getCaretakerDetails() {
    return this.caretakerDetails;
}

public void setCaretakerDetails(CaretakerDetails caretakerDetails) {
    this.caretakerDetails = caretakerDetails;
}

@Column(name = "Device_Number", nullable = false)
public String getDeviceNumber() {
    return this.deviceNumber;
}

public void setDeviceNumber(String deviceNumber) {
    this.deviceNumber = deviceNumber;
}

@Column(name = "Created_Date", nullable = false)
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return this.createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

}
```

Can anyone here tell me what I am doing wrong here? Am I missing something here?
Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Try setting the updateble to false : @Column(name = "Device_Id", updatable = false, nullable = false)

Comment: Still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to put `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` instead `@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)` in your class ?